# Output an altered list given a list in R

Tags: r

I have a list like so:

```
animals = c('dog','cat','mouse')
```

Is there a way given the `animals` list to generate the this list: `c('dog' = 'Dog', 'cat' = 'Cat', 'mouse' = 'Mouse')`?

Comment: To clarify, with the `=` sign?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We may use `str_to_title`

```
library(stringr)
setNames(str_to_title(animals), animals)
```

-output

```
  dog     cat   mouse 
  "Dog"   "Cat" "Mouse"
```

---

Or use `sub`

```
setNames(sub("(.)", "\\U\\1", animals, perl = TRUE), animals)
```

---

or may also do

```
setNames({`<-`(substr(animals, 1, 1), toupper(substr(animals, 1, 1))); animals}, animals)
    dog     cat   mouse 
  "Dog"   "Cat" "Mouse"
```

Answer (score 1):

Also you can use `tools::toTitleCase()`

```
tools::toTitleCase(animals)
#[1] "Dog"   "Cat"   "Mouse"
```

or

```
setNames(tools::toTitleCase(animals), animals)
#---
    dog     cat   mouse 
  "Dog"   "Cat" "Mouse"
```